# Javascript comparing an instance in one array with a whole other array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

In summary I am trying to build a swear filter where I have a static array called "badWords" which holds many profane words.

My script then lifts all text values from a form into another array called "fieldValues".

It then iterates through the fieldValues and should compare the string values with the whole array of "badWords" and if found trigger a simple response for now.

The code is not producing any errors but it is not producing expected outputs either, I was hoping you could give me insight into where I went wrong with it.

**Code**

```
// get all the inputs from "editor_form"
var $inputs = $('#editor_form :input');

var fieldValues = new Array();
var i = 0;

//for each field place it in array
$inputs.each(function() 
{
    fieldValues[i] = $(this).val();
    i++;
});

var swearWord;
for (i = 0; i < fieldValues.length; i++)
{
    if (fieldValues[i] == function()
    {
        //this bit i think is wrong, i think it only does one loop in this level then jumps back up
        for (x = 0; x < badWords.length; x++)
        {
            return badWords[x];
        }
    })

    //warning message   
    {
        window.alert("Bad word found");
    }       
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Hmm why did my question get downvoted?

Comment: I didn't downvote but do you notice how it's easier to read now that its formatting was improved ?

Comment: Once you've fixed the above, as a next step what happens if the user types more than one word into the same field? You'd get a `fieldValues` array entry with a string like `"three bad words"`, but comparing that to a word from the `badWords` array won't ever match with `==`.

Comment: Yess @nnnnnn , so I will be using Regex for that to search for strings within a string :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can fix your existing code like this :

```
function isBad(word) {
     for (x = 0; x < badWords.length; x++) {
         if (badWords[x]==word) return true;
     }
     return false;
}
for (i = 0; i < fieldValues.length; i++) {
   if (isBad(fieldValues[i])) {
       window.alert("Bad word found : " + fieldValues[i]);
   }
}
```

But your bad words form, logically, a set, not an array. You should use an object as map to find them in a fast way.

```
// build a set of the bad words
var badWordsSet = {};
for (x = 0; x < badWords.length; x++) badWordsSet[badWords[x]]=true;
// then use it
for (i = 0; i < fieldValues.length; i++) {
   if (badWordsSet[fieldValues[i]]) {
       window.alert("Bad word found : " + fieldValues[i]);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, my set is alphabetically sorted. So to improve performance I will incorporate a binary search within your code! :)

Comment: Are you sure you need it ? You should profile the set solution before to ensure you should optimize it. Javascript access to properties is very fast and is native code. I'm really not sure your binary search will be faster.

Comment: Hmm interesting problem now, it is not actually returning expected results. A field value is being passed correctly to the isBad() function and the forloop is iterating through my array but the evaluation does not seem to be working correctly.

Comment: i.e. it should be picking up a match but its not. I noticed in your code you have var badWordsSet = {}; . I have var badWordsSet = [];

Comment: In the second version, I convert the array (`[]`) to a set (`{}`) which is backuped by a hash table (in fact, not really, it's compiled by V8 engine in some cases).

Comment: Thanks, the problem was fixed with placing regex expression in the evalution.

Answer (score 1):

The bit you believe is wrong really is. You should not compare `fieldValues[i]` to the function you create but rather you should compare this value to each of the `badWords` in turn. No need for another function there, just an inner cycle.